# Creating mobile LED projects with LED strips, USB, and an 8xAA battery pack

Tags: led, batteries, usb, led-strip

I'm trying to make some LED clothing.

I'm planning on buying some [LED strips](https://www.amazon.ca/Changing-Control-Kitchen-Bedroom-Waterproof/dp/B07RFFJ7YL/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=led%20strips&qid=1564552317&s=gateway&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1), which require a 12V power supply. I plan on buying some [battery packs](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B078NSYCZJ/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A23PACNCKQFE9H&psc=1) for the power source. To link the power source to the lights, I plan to use these USB ends that I happen to own that look like this:

[image: Blurry USB Thing]

I took this out of a mobile phone charger power bank type thing.
I then plan to plug a 1-4 USB input hub into the USB so I can power multiple separate things. I own [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Anker-4-Port-Macbook-Surface-Notebook/dp/B00XMD7KPU/ref=sr_1_3?crid=3QSOURZUN1N1O&keywords=usb%20hub&qid=1564558804&s=gateway&sprefix=usb%20%2Ckitchen%2C210&sr=8-3) and plan on using one that came with rock back about a decade ago.

Then because I own so many micro USB cables, I want to plug the USB end into the hub, cut off the micro-USB end, and solder the wires onto the LED strips

Is my logic sound? I've never really done anything like this before. I've heard that USB hubs might convert the 12V to 5V. Is there other wiring would make more sense for what I'm doing? The main thing I need is for one battery to go to about four devices. I couldn't really figure this out.

Comment: No it is not a good plan to use 5V USB for 12V LEDstrips or AA batteries unless rechargeable between short term use. You must estimate the Watt s and Voltage of load and Watt-hours and range of  battery voltage to delivery this capacity with the load current vs V.    For 5V RGB LEDstrips USB hubs designed for 12W load ports may be suitable for < 12W 5V RGB types. These come in 4 and 8 port (65W) hubs with 5V 65W chargers with 2.4A max and up to 65W total.

Comment: Forget about the USB hubs. Just buy the appropriate connector to mate with the LED controller and wire it to the batteries. It might be a 2.1 x 5.5 mm plug like this: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=CP3-1000-ND  I recommend eneloop rechargeable batteries since they have a fairly flat discharge curve. The LED strips draw some serious power at maximum brightness, the batteries won't last long. Worse, at maximum brightness, the voltage may be dragged down enough to cause other issues.

Comment: The Power supply with that strip is a 2A 12V power adapter, If that much power is needed you would need to make sure your USB will handle that. A mobile power bank also will likely not last long. Just may want to check before you plan a build what the requirements are.